# DocuSign Status not being created randomly & hexadecimal value 0x0B is an invalid character

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

Every once in a while, some envelopes don't get the DocuSign Status record created for them in Salesforce. The envelope looks correct in DocuSign and signers can continue their signing session but the DocuSign integration records are not getting created.

What to do when some DocuSign Status records are not created in Salesforce randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely, there is an error in the envelope. It might not be intuitive to find out what went wrong.

In order to find out what was the issue, the first step is to check the DocuSign Connect logs.

- Go to DocuSign Admin > Connect
- Click on Logs and look for the envelope that was failing
- Click on the log and check out the 'Log Details'

In this example, the issue is with a user input that added a C0 control code of `0x0B` in one of the fields. Here is the user input:

> Variablesin Association

Therefore, since the hexadecimal value 0x0B is an invalid character, this envelope integration is going to fail and the DocuSign Status will not be created in Salesforce.

[image: The reason that DocuSign Status wasn't created]